# AWS parameter store access in lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda

I'm trying to access the parameter store in an AWS lambda function.  This is my code, pursuant to the documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html

```
var ssm = new AWS.SSM({apiVersion: '2014-11-06'});
var ssm_params1 = {
    Name: 'XXXX', /* required */
    WithDecryption: true
};

ssm.getParameter(ssm_params1, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     clientId = data.value;
});
```

Upon execution, I get the error:

"TypeError: ssm.getParameter is not a function"

Did amazon change this without changing the docs?  Did this function move to another type of object?

Comment: I have a c# lambda and I’m trying to get a parameter. It seems to have trouble due to IAM permission. What policy is required for a lambda to get a parameter value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is that Amazon must have ditched the getParameter() method in favor of only maintaining one method getParameter(s)().  But they didn't update the documentation. That method seems to work just fine.

Comment: The API version of the sdk clients does not change when new functions are added as you implied in a comment on another answer.. For example, S3 is still on version "2006-03-01" which indicates backwards compatibility, not when it was last updated. Lambda does not run on the latest sdk version. At time of writing this it's running "2.108.0" while the latest is "2.131.0". The method you are trying to use very much exists in the sdks, you most likely happened to be on a version of the sdk that did not support them at the time of this question. You also have the option to bundle the sdk yourself.

Comment: This is not correct. Both methods are still available in AWS.

Answer (score 3):

Please check and try the latest version of the SDK. It is not the case that Amazon has ditched the getParameter method in favor of only getParameters. The fact is the method is getParameter, together with getParametersByPath, is newly added methods. Old version of SDK would not resolve these methods.

Comment: This is being executed by a Lambda function.  I used the same API version of the SSM library that was in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried both getParameter and getParameters function, and both of them are working fine.

It could be possible that you are getting an error since you are passing "apiVersion: '2014-11-06'" to the SSM constructor.

Do not pass any apiVersion parameter to the function. It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in AWS that is not including correct sdk version in certain environments. This can be confirmed by logging the sdk version used.

```
console.log("AWS-SDK Version: " + require('aws-sdk/package.json').version);
```

Including the required aws-sdk package solved the problem for us.

Try adding the following in package.json:

```
    "aws-sdk": "^2.339.0"
```